# What is the difference between bond enthalpy and bond formation enthalpy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I came across the following while going through my textbook

> The standard enthalpy of reaction is related to bond enthalpies of reactants and products in gas phase reactions as: $$\Delta H^{\circ}_r = \Sigma(\textrm{bond enthalpies})_{\textrm{reactants}}-\Sigma(\textrm{bond enthalpies})_{\textrm{products}}$$  If we use enthalpy of bond formation, then $$\Delta H^{\circ}_r = \Sigma \Delta_f H^{\circ}_{\textrm{bonds of products}}-\Sigma\Delta_f H^{\circ}_{\textrm{bonds of reactants}}$$

#### My Questions

- How is *bond formation enthalpy* different from *bond enthalpy*?
- Why does the equation gets reversed when we are using bond formation enthalpy?
- *Bond formation enthalpy* and *enthalpy of formation* of a substance are different, right?

Comment: Indeed precisely as written the box means nothing. Stick to the answer you have got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "enthalpy of bond formation" you are referring to is simply "enthalpy of formation", that is, the enthalpy of reaction when one mole of a substance is formed in its reference state from its constituent elements.
On the other hand, "bond enthalpy" is the enthalpy required to break one mole of a particular type of bond, all of this under standard conditions.
These quantities represent opposite phenomena, hence the equation gets reversed.